# Filling in markers in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've been searching around and digging through the pgfplots manual and I can't quite seem to find a good answer for this.  I'm trying to make a graph with "open circles" to indicate where the function is undefined.  Right now I'm using the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:6,
    xtick={-2,...,6},
    ytick={-20,-10,...,40},
    xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,
    xlabel={$x$},title={Graph of $y=g(x)$}
]
\addplot+[mark=none]{(20/9)*(x^3/3-(3/2)*x^2)};
\addplot+[only marks,mark=o,mark options={scale=2},text mark as node=true] coordinates {
    (-2,-20)
    (6,40)
    (5,10)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This results in the following picture:

[image]

Is there a simple way to fill in those circles so we don't see the graph behind them?  I've tried adding "fill=white", "fill opacity=0", etc to the "mark options", but to no avail.  I've also tried using the tikz command \draw to manually draw a circle, but that didn't seem to work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`mark=o` is an unfilled circle. Use `mark=*` instead:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:6,
    xtick={-2,...,6},
    ytick={-20,-10,...,40},
    xmajorgrids=true,ymajorgrids=true,
    xlabel={$x$},title={Graph of $y=g(x)$}
]
\addplot+[mark=none]{(20/9)*(x^3/3-(3/2)*x^2)};
\addplot+[only marks,mark=*,mark options={scale=2, fill=white},text mark as node=true] coordinates {
    (-2,-20)
    (6,40)
    (5,10)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```